# Format date of JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using the JQuery datapicker for my date input.. I have this code

```
<td class="auditTable_sub_headers" id="logging_from_cell">
   <input name="logging_from" id="logging_from" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox",  "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy" }' class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
</td>
```

And this JS to return the value

```
var loggingfrom = document.getElementById("logging_from").value;
```

I get this value back: 
2014-07-17

This is the wrong format. Is there a way to return the value as format DD-MM-YY (17-JUL-14)?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
It answers this question on multiple occasions.

Comment: I tried "data-options='{"mode": "calbox",  "dateFormat": "dd-MM-y" }'" and still the same output, I'm slightly confused.

Comment: That's not how the documentation said to do it.  I had to do this about a month ago and it's literally one line of code.  Of course I'm not going to give it to you, but it's extremely simple.

Comment: did you look through any of the number of related posts in right sidebar that have the same issues? get the date value using datepicker api

Comment: I looked through some related issues and found that I was using the wrong JQuery to change the format. I was using an older version of the datepicker so the code was slightly different. To fix it I used the following code using the website below: {"overrideDateFormat":"%d-%b-%y"} - http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/dateformat.html